# Trying to convert a csv to HDF5 and read it using vaex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, hdf5, vaex

Used this piece of code to convert the csv into HDF5 with a given chunk size

```
dv = vaex.from_csv('Wager-Win_April-Jul.csv', convert=True, chunk_size=5_000_000)
```

But getting this error while executing the above

```
.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vaex/__init__.py in from_csv(filename_or_buffer, copy_index, **kwargs)
    484     """
    485     import pandas as pd
--> 486     return from_pandas(pd.read_csv(filename_or_buffer, **kwargs), copy_index=copy_index)
    487 
    488 

TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert'
```

Is there any problem with package installation ?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have the latest version of vaex installed. Seems like this was a later addition to the version you are currently running.